# Why this Clang ASTMatcher cause wrong polymorphic conversion?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I am Writing a tool using clang as frontend and matching some AST nodes.

I create ASTMatcher as follow:

```
void Rule_1_2_1::registerMatchers(MatchFinder *Finder)
{
    DeclarationMatcher Matcher = decl(hasType(builtinType().bind("non-typedef"))).bind("non-typedef-decl");
    Finder->addMatcher(Matcher, this);
}

void Rule_1_2_1::run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult &Result)
{
    if (const BuiltinType *type = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<BuiltinType>("non-typedef")) {
        if (!type->isFloatingPoint() && !type->isInteger())
            return;
        if (const Decl *decl = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<Decl>("non-typedef-decl")) {
            DiagnosticsEngine &DE = Result.Context->getDiagnostics();
            Context->report(this->CheckerName, this->ReportMsg, DE, decl->getLocStart(), DiagnosticIDs::Note);
        }
    }
}
```

But compiler gives me following errors:

```
/usr/include/clang/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchersInternal.h: In instantiation of ‘clang::ast_matchers::internal::PolymorphicMatcherWithParam1<MatcherT, P1, ReturnTypesF>::operator clang::ast_matchers::internal::Matcher<From>() const [with T = clang::Decl; MatcherT = clang::ast_matchers::internal::matcher_hasType0Matcher; P1 = clang::ast_matchers::internal::Matcher<clang::QualType>; ReturnTypesF = void(clang::ast_matchers::internal::TypeList<clang::Expr, clang::TypedefNameDecl, clang::ValueDecl>)]’:
../src/modules/gjb/Rule_1_2_1.cpp:18:81:   required from here
/usr/include/clang/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchersInternal.h:1104:5: Error：static assertion failed: right polymorphic conversion
     static_assert(TypeListContainsSuperOf<ReturnTypes, T>::value,
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I know i am not familiar with Clang ASTMatcher and the documentation may be not very detailed.

Why this error happened?

line 18 is the line of Matcher defined.

Comment: Do you have a full instantiation backtrace?

Comment: @SebastianRedl Other message is `In file included from ,,,`

Comment: I guess the reason may be there is no sub `node` could cast to `type` in `decl`. If clang coulde provide a comparison between `ASTMatcher` and the result of `clang -cc1 -ast-dump`, things will be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer since it is too long for a comment, but it is only a guess at your problem, not a definite solution.

The error looks like it occurs when you compile your matcher, not when you apply it. Which means you misused the API, not that it doesn't match anything in your code. The AST matcher API checks that you don't do things that make no sense, like filtering on an attribute that may not even exist.

In your case, you are looking for declarations that have some type. But asking a declaration what its type is doesn't necessarily make sense. The `Decl` class in Clang is the root of the entire declaration hierarchy and includes things like `EmptyDecl` (which represents simply a single semicolon outside a statement context) and `StaticAssertDecl` (`static_assert`), neither of which have a type.

Every node matcher has type information on what nodes it produces. Every narrowing matcher has information on what nodes it applies to. It is checked at compile time that these are compatible.

They interesting parts of the error message are not the unfortunately vague message, but the static_assert condition itself and the listing of the active parameter substitutions.

`TypeListContainsSuperOf<ReturnTypes, T>::value` is the condition, i.e. "the type list must contain a type that is a supertype of T".

But what is T, and what does the type list contain? The error message says: "In instantiation of  with " and then lists substitutions. There we learn that:

- `T = clang::Decl`
- `MatcherT = clang::ast_matchers::internal::matcher_hasType0Matcher`
- `ReturnTypesF = void(clang::ast_matchers::internal::TypeList<clang::Expr, clang::TypedefNameDecl, clang::ValueDecl>)`

`ReturnTypes` is not directly listed, but it's pretty obvious that it refers to the parameter type of `ReturnTypesF`, i.e. the `TypeList` in there.

This tells us the following things:

- The `decl()` matcher produces `clang::Decl` nodes.
- The matcher we're currently validating is the `hasType()` matcher.
- The `hasType()` matcher can work on any of `clang::Expr`, `clang::TypedefNameDecl`, and `clang::ValueDecl`.

But `Decl` is a supertype of `TypedefNameDecl` and `ValueDecl`, not the other way around, and unrelated to `Expr`. This means that the static assertion fails. The `decl()` matcher does not produce nodes that `hasType()` can work with.

Depending on your exact goals, using `valueDecl()` instead might work.

Comment: Yes, i finally use `declaratorDecl()`, and it works. Originally, my choose was `declaratorDecl()`, but then i noticed that the example of `declaratorDecl()` in `AST Matcher Reference` isn't include the function declaration, so, i turned to use `decl()`.But `declaratorDecl()` matches function declaration successfully.